# How to export all actions (animations) in blender to a file. fbx?

Tags: c#, xna, unity-game-engine, blender, fbx

I'm encountering a problem exporting models with animations from Blender.  When exported my XNA project models contain only the first animation even though I am selecting "All Animation" in the settings.

Can someone please help me understand why all of my animations are not being exported/imported?

Here is my configuration:

[image: Blender Config]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the problem !!! I must download and install XNA 4.0 Refresh and all it's work !!
http://xboxforums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/106701.aspx